# IIS Reverse Proxy to Node.js - Static Compression

Tags: node.js, iis

- Windows Server 2012
- IIS 8.5

We have setup IIS as a reverse proxy to a Node.js web server (both running on the same box). I cannot get Static Compression to work for resources served from Node.js, through IIS.

- To rewrite request URLs we use the URL Rewrite module with an Inbound rule.
  There are no Outbound rules.
- Compression is disabled in Node.js - we want IIS to do the compression on the response from Node.js
- **We have tested Dynamic Compression (using default GZip compression) and everything is working fine.**
- **Static Compression is working but only for files local to the IIS site (i.e. not served from Node.js), when the Inbound rule is disabled.**
- This [page](https://forums.iis.net/p/1165899/1937448.aspx) says that "*Oubound rewriting cannot be used together with IIS static compression*." However, we don't have any Outbound rules.
- I've enabled Failed Request Tracing but cannot see any STATIC_COMPRESSION_START entries in the trace when the Inbound rule is enabled.
- At the IIS web server configuration, I've tried various settings, such as staticCompressionIgnoreHitFrequency="true", see sample below.

Q. How do we enable Static Compression when reverse proxying to Node.js?

Samples from server config:

```
<httpCompression directory="C:\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files" minFileSizeForComp="1" noCompressionForHttp10="false" noCompressionForProxies="false" noCompressionForRange="false" staticCompressionIgnoreHitFrequency="true" staticCompressionEnableCpuUsage="1" >
        <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" staticCompressionLevel="9" />
        <staticTypes>
            <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
        </staticTypes>
        <dynamicTypes>
            <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
        </dynamicTypes>
    </httpCompression>
```

Samples from site web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear></clear>
        <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:3000/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="false" />


  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried using IIS as a reverse proxy to another IIS site (rather than Node) and pasted a related question here: https://serverfault.com/questions/909149/iis-rewrite-module-and-static-compression

This lead to the solution of Node question above. You need to:

1) Forget about the Static Compression module (which is disabled when using ARR for the reverse proxy) and instead enable ARR caching (with compression enabled). This will Gzip the ARR cached content. **However**....

2) I noticed that this did not work for JS files. The reason for this is that our Node server was setting the Content-Type for JS files to "application/javascript; charset=UTF-8". ARR is configured by default to look for a content type without the character encoding.

To fix this, in \Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config, add a`<add mimeType="application/javascript; charset=UTF-8" enabled="true" />` mapping as per:

```
<diskCache>
        <driveLocation path="C:\inetpub\arrCache" maxUsage="5" />
        <compression>
            <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/javascript; charset=UTF-8" enabled="true" />
        </compression>
    </diskCache>
```